# React Native: Keychain autofill not working until TextInput is clicked again

Tags: react-native, keychain, autofill

I am building a react-native app, using expo@43.0.0 and I am testing on a device with iOS 15.1

I have two TextInputs for the login:

```
    <TextInput
        textContentType='username'
        autoComplete={true}
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(input) => setEmail(input)}
      />

      <TextInput
        autoComplete={true}
        textContentType='password'
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(input) => setPassword(input)}
      />
```

### Problem:

When I click into the TextInput for the username, the keyboard comes in. I now click the key icon for keychain and I can select credentials from the icloud-keychain. After selecting the credentials, the keyboard disappears again, but the two TextInputs remain empty. When I now click into one of the two TextInput Components, both are filled correctly.

Anyone ran into something similar or has a solution, that the both inputs are filled as soon as the credentials are selected, without clicking them again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my app, input fields with keychain usage wouldn't show the value until I clicked on it again.

But the solution was had nothing to do with the input fields but the fact that the application changes state when you are in the keychain selection screen, this resulted in displaying my anti screen screenshot which when displayed updated the root of the component tree.

What generates the bug for me.

Hope it help